# Filling WPF combobox with Active Directory users taking too long

Tags: wpf, vb.net, performance, combobox, active-directory

I have a combobox bound to a datatable that I fill with user's names from active directory. This code takes about a minute to complete. Is there a better way that I am missing?

```
Function users() As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim idCoulumn As DataColumn
    Dim nameCoulumn As DataColumn

    Dim dirEntry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=local")

    Dim oSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    Dim oResults As SearchResultCollection

    oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName")
    oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")
    oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
    oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    oSearcher.Filter = "objectCategory=person"
    oResults = oSearcher.FindAll

    dt = New DataTable()
    idCoulumn = New DataColumn("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    nameCoulumn = New DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    dt.Columns.Add(idCoulumn)
    dt.Columns.Add(nameCoulumn)

    For Each oResult In oResults
        With oResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
            If .Properties("cn").Value <> "" AndAlso .Properties("samAccountName").Value <> "" AndAlso .Properties("sn").Value <> "" Then
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID") = .Properties("samAccountName").Value
                dr("Name") = String.Format("{0},{1} : {2}", .Properties("sn").Value, .Properties("givenname").Value, .Properties("samAccountName").Value)
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            End If
        End With
    Next

    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Name"

    Return dt

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Spevy helped me get to this solution with his proposed answer.

I changed my Directory entry to:

```
Dim dirEntry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myDomain")
```

I set my search filter:

```
oSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user))"
```

And changed my if statement to:

```
If .Properties("samAccountName").Value <> "" AndAlso .Properties("sn").Value <> "" Then
```

I am not sure what adding these lines of code really do but I get the same results whether they are there or not, so I removed them:

```
oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName")
oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")
oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the sn and cn properties, try the filter below and remove your if.

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=*))
```

This queries for all users with an existing samAccount Name. Which should eliminate the need for the if statement and checks for SN or CN. You may also consider binding to something lighter then a Datatable.

Beyond that your code looks pretty tight.  You may just have to put this in its own thread.

Comment: Great! This wasn't quite the answer but it really helped me getting there. Thank you.